# What characters are not allowed in the rpm "Release" ?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Machine 1

```
#uname -r
Machine 1:3.2.45-0.6.wd.561.41.269.metal1.x86_64
#rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.8.0
```

While trying rpmbuild I encountered 
Illegal char ''' in: Release: 25.'4283295'.mybranch

There was error in the script I wrote which appended the quotes around the number.

On machine 2

```
# uname -r
2.6.16.33-xenU
# rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.4.2
```

Here rpmbuild seemed to work with single quoted number in the name:
myapp-1.4.25.'4283295'.mybranch.x86_64.rpm

I gathered that single quote is not allowed in the Release in the earlier case.
What is the set of characters that I should always avoid ?

Are there differences due to the rpmbuild version ?

I failed to find allowed characters in the rpm name/version/release.
any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The question appears to equate *version* and *release* tags.  The tools can treat these differently.

In making a script, single-quotes would be "eaten" by a shell.  What gets *stored* in the RPM database are the actual characters.  RPM uses period `.` as a delimiter, so you cannot use *that* as part of a version/release value.

Generally alpha/numerics, hyphen (minus) and a few other punctuation characters *may* be used in each field, but the tools and policies will further limit that rule.  These are all from the POSIX character set (not mentioned and not supported would be UTF-8, it seems).

According to Fedora, the [release tag](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Release_Tag) has to be an *integer* followed by an *optional* distribution tag.  [Another source](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/RPMAndDebVersioning) says that hyphen cannot appear in a release tag.  Those two differ about whether tilde is allowed, and the latter states that plus `+` and colon `:` are allowed (but not the former).

Further reading:

- [Packaging Guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines) (Fedora)
- [RPM and DEB Versioning](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/RPMAndDebVersioning)

Comment: Somebody on my team had a branch named "`=a`" for some reason, and we found out that `=` is not allowed either.